# WSO2 Control several APIs with the same endpoint with XACML poicies

Tags: api, wso2, xacml

I have followed the tutorial for enforcing policies on API calls
http://wso2.com/library/tutorials/2016/02/tutorial-how-to-enable-role-based-access-control-for-wso2-api-manager-using-xacml/

It wasn't easy but I got something up and running. I can change access to different endpoints of an API depending on the user's role.

I have a question. Here's a fictional setup to complete the tutorial:

- API `EduCollege`, with endpoints `/student/info` and `/staff/info` (tutorial)
- API `Prison`, with endpoints `/prisoner/info` and `/staff/info` (note that it's the same endpoint)

I write a policy `EDUCollegePolicy` that enables only those with role `college_admin` to access `/staff/info` (tutorial).

But there seems to be no way to restrict these college admins from accessing staff info of the prison!
The field `resource` only contains info about the endpoint.

Is there any way, using this setup, to limit by API?

Or does it maybe require a different JAR add-in, that would send a `resource` value set to `API/version/endpoint` instead of just `/endpoint`?

Oh, by the way: I couldn't set policies according to the endpoints provided in the tutorial. It doesn't seem that it's `/staff/info`, but I got it to work with regexp `.*staff.*info.*`. Not nice. I wonder what the actual resource sent from JAR to PDP is, I couldn't find it in any logs, including IDS logs (the IDS acts as PDP)